# javascript post form doesnt send post parameters

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to submit a javascript form like following

```
node.on("click", function(d){
    var name =encodeURIComponent(d.ancestors()[0].data.id) ;

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "clickable_cluster");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); 

  hiddenField.setAttribute("user_name", "{{user_name}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("thresh1", "{{thresh1}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("thresh2", "{{thresh2}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("thresh3", "{{thresh3}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("pthresh1", "{{pthresh1}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("pthresh2", "{{pthresh2}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("pthresh3", "{{pthresh3}}");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("node", "name");
  form.appendChild(hiddenField);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  //window.open('', 'view');

    //window.location.assign("clickable_cluster", '_blank');
    form.submit();


  });
```

But, the flask server in backend doesnt receives any of these post parameters.

```
@app.route('/clickable_cluster', methods=['POST'])
def clicable_cluster():

    print "request got ", request.form.items() # is []
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you are using a form for the submission?

Comment: @Icepickle I just want to make a post request with some params when a user clicks on a node..I tried another method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878723/make-a-post-request-to-a-link-when-a-d3-node-is-clicked) but then it doesnt open a new tab.. I am open for any method that helps me just make a post request in a new tab.

Comment: Post requests, btw, would generally send the name of your `input` element, and it's `value` to the server, that would be the reason why your server doesn't receive anything, as you are only setting attributes on a nameless input element. As for the other question, it looks interesting, I will check there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general reason why you don't get any data submitted by your form request is because a form request generally sends all input fields with it's name & value as content.

Currently you are only setting attributes on a nameless input field.

You could generalize the adding of your form elements in the following way. The `attachToForm` function will take a form and an object as input  parameters and will create appropriate input fields for each property inside your object.

```
function attachToForm( form, content ) {
  Object.keys( content ).forEach( prop => {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = prop;
    input.value = content[prop];
    form.appendChild( input );
  });
}

node.on("click", function(d){
    var name =encodeURIComponent(d.ancestors()[0].data.id) ;

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "clickable_cluster");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    attachToForm( form, {
      "user_name": "{{user_name}}",
      "thresh1": "{{thresh1}}",
      "thresh2": "{{thresh2}}",
      "thresh3": "{{thresh3}}",
      "pthresh1": "{{pthresh1}}",
      "pthresh2": "{{pthresh2}}",
      "pthresh3": "{{pthresh3}}",
      "node": "name"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  });
```

I am guessing that the values you are sending are placeholders for the real data or part of your rendering engine, but generally it should do the trick.

Comment: I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined at line `input.name = prop;`

Comment: I think, it should be hidden field and then it works :)

Comment: @Fraz Woops, sorry, I didn't really test it, corrected it to match the variable name :)